# Chain rule for inner product.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Am I using the chain rule correctly to calculate $$  \nabla_x\langle f(x),M f(x) \rangle= \nabla_u\langle u,M u\rangle |_{u=f(x)} D_xf(x) ~~~?$$

where $D_x$ is the matrix of first derivatives of $f$.

Comment: Yes, your work so far is correct. Keep in mind that in this context, the $\nabla_u$ term should have shape $1 \times n$.

Answer (score 1):

$h(x) = \langle f(x),M f(x) \rangle$ is the composition $h = g \circ f$ where

$$g(u) = \langle u,M u \rangle.$$

The chain rule states that

$$h^\prime(x) = g^\prime(f(x)) \circ f^\prime(x).$$

So yes, what you wrote is correct, knowing that
$$g^\prime(u).k = \langle u,M k \rangle + \langle k,M u \rangle$$ which leads to

$$h^\prime(x).k = \langle f(x),M (f^\prime(x).k) \rangle + \langle f^\prime(x).k,M .f(x) \rangle$$